# Linter rules for single or multiline object literals

Tags: javascript, eslint, object-literal

I try to set up ESLint rules for both linting and autoformatting of object literal.

This snippet should cause linter error:

```
let obj = {    foo: 1,
  bar: 2, baz: 3
};
```

And I expect it to be fixed to either:

```
let obj = { foo: 1, bar: 2, baz: 3 };
```

Or:

```
let obj = {
    foo: 1,
    bar: 2,
    baz: 3
};
```

I have several rules including [object-property-newline](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/object-property-newline) but they are not enough. Here's a [demo](https://eslint.org/demo#eyJ0ZXh0IjoiLyplc2xpbnQgaW5kZW50OiBcImVycm9yXCIqL1xuLyplc2xpbnQgbm8tbXVsdGktc3BhY2VzOiBcImVycm9yXCIqL1xuLyplc2xpbnQgb2JqZWN0LWN1cmx5LXNwYWNpbmc6IFtcImVycm9yXCIsIFwiYWx3YXlzXCJdKi9cbi8qZXNsaW50IG9iamVjdC1wcm9wZXJ0eS1uZXdsaW5lOiBcImVycm9yXCIqL1xubGV0IG9iaiA9IHsgICAgZm9vOiAxLFxuICBiYXI6IDIsIGJhejogM1xufTsiLCJvcHRpb25zIjp7InBhcnNlck9wdGlvbnMiOnsiZWNtYVZlcnNpb24iOjExLCJzb3VyY2VUeXBlIjoic2NyaXB0IiwiZWNtYUZlYXR1cmVzIjp7fX0sInJ1bGVzIjp7fSwiZW52Ijp7fX19):

```
/*eslint indent: "error"*/
/*eslint no-multi-spaces: "error"*/
/*eslint object-curly-spacing: ["error", "always"]*/
/*eslint object-property-newline: ["error", { allowAllPropertiesOnSameLine: true }] */
let obj = {    foo: 1,
  bar: 2, baz: 3
};
```

The result is:

```
let obj = { foo: 1,
    bar: 2,
    baz: 3
};
```

These rules don't address inconsistent curly braces. This passes too:

```
let obj = { foo: 1, bar: 2, baz: 3
};
```

Is it possible to address this with ESLint core rules? Is this possible with third-party rules?

Comment: Maybe [`object-curly-newline`](https://eslint.org/docs/rules/object-curly-newline).

Comment: Thanks, indeed, object-curly-newline with consistent flag is what I needed. It allows empty multiline object but I can live with it.